# How to create a vector with sequential filenames and numbers in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector, paste

Could you please help me?

I have a `list` of `matrices` read into `R`. Each matrix was randomized 10 times, and then a metric was calculated for each randomization. I want to store the results in an organized data frame that reflects the sequence of randomizations.

How can I build a `vector` with the sequence of filenames + numbers, so I know which result refers to which randomization? Later, I'll add this vector to a `data frame` to label the results.

This is what my code looks like so far:

Let's assume I have a vector with the names of the files read into R and that it looks something like this:

```
files <- paste("file", seq(1:3), sep = "")
```

Each file was randomized 10 times and then a metric was calculated for each randomization:

```
rand <- seq(1:10)
```

Now I want to create a vector with a sequence of filenames and randomizations:

```
files.rand <- paste(files, rand, sep = "_")
```

The final sequence produced by this code does not reflect the actual sequence in which the randomizations were analyzed.

I need the sequence to look like this:

```
"file1_1"  "file1_2"  "file1_3"  "file1_4"  "file1_5"
"file1_6"  "file1_7"  "file1_8"  "file1_9"  "file1_10"
"file2_1" "file2_2" "file2_3" "file2_4" ...
```

The sequential numbers should be added to the name of file1, then they should be added to the name of file2, and so on, in order.

How could this result be achieved? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each file to have each sequence pasted on the end in the order that you already have the files and sequence sorted, then I think you just want to use `lapply` on a `paste` function and `unlist` it like so:

```
files.rand <- lapply(files,function(x) paste(x,rand,sep = "_"))
files.rand <- unlist(files.rand)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outer` :

```
c(t(outer(files, rand, paste, sep = '_')))

#[1] "file1_1"  "file1_2"  "file1_3"  "file1_4"  "file1_5"  "file1_6" 
#[7] "file1_7"  "file1_8"  "file1_9"  "file1_10" "file2_1"  "file2_2" 
#[13] "file2_3"  "file2_4"  "file2_5"  "file2_6"  "file2_7"  "file2_8" 
#[19] "file2_9"  "file2_10" "file3_1"  "file3_2"  "file3_3"  "file3_4" 
#[25] "file3_5"  "file3_6"  "file3_7"  "file3_8"  "file3_9"  "file3_10"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply sort *files.rand*, but this would stumble over the alphanumeric order, which is not the same as numeric order. A simple workaround is to add leading zeros to your numbers (replace "%02i" with "%03i" for 100 random numbers etc.):

```
files.rand <- paste(files, sprintf("%02i", rand), sep = "_")
files.rand <- sort(files.rand)
```

Comment: Thank you! Nevertheless, your code is producing only 10 combinations of filename + number. There should be 30 in total (3 filenames * 10 numbers). How can we fix this, please?